# How to setup Documentum Content Server and Webtop 6.7 on local PC

Tags: documentum, webtop

I want to setup Documentum Content Server 6.7 with Webtop client on my local PC. As I am new to Documentum, I don't know whether community version for Documentum is available or not.

Please guide me and provide useful links for setup and installation if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install Documentum platform on any computer there is minimal requirements to follow though. 
However there is no community version of installation setup, you need be part of partnership program somehow to be able to download setups.

Comment: Thanks @Miki... Can you be more specific on which parternship programs? Or please provide links for the same.

Comment: @Miki, I think there was a development edition which you can download and use, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Sergi I still think it was intended only for partners, but I might be wrong, check it out.

Comment: @Shubham Khuje sorry, but I cannot, its not public service or something like that. Try navigate on site.